# DataSource function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently worked on a project that involved taking xml data, converting it to json, and parsing it for use in my app. One of my errors had to do with the `DataSource.get()` function callback in the controller, in which I called the service that converted my xml, I assigned the converted data to `$scope.data`. I then tried to parse the the converted data outside of the function and assign the pieces to different `$scope` elements. My error was that I didn't parse the data inside the function - why can't the converted data, once set to `$scope.data`, be used outside of the `DataSource.get()` function? I'm new to angularjs and haven't found any explanation as to why the app doesn't like it. If anyone can provide just a brief explanation, it would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m42wOY?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can. You can definitely use the value of `$scope.data` outside of the `DataSource.get()` function. However - you have to make sure it's available first.

So if you had this before:

```
DataSource.get().success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
}

// Do something with $scope.data
```

Then, because of the asynchronous `get()` method, the runtime would continue on the `// Do something with $scope.data` line, BEFORE the `success()` callback function was called, and thus BEFORE `$scope.data` was set.

You're free to write  either:

```
DataSource.get().success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;

    dosomethingwithdata();
}

dosomethingwithdata = function() {
    // Do something with $scope.data    
}
```

This should work - since `$scope.data` will be available. However, I don't like this very much, since the function is implicitly dependent on `$scope.data` which is not so nice and makes it hard to test for instance. Nicer would be:

```
DataSource.get().success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;

    dosomethingwithdata($scope.data);
}

dosomethingwithdata = function(data) {
    // Do something with data. Which is a bit safer
    // so you make the dependency of this function
    // on a data input explicit
}
```

So this question is more about asynchonicity in JavaScript than AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!